# What's a good IPv6 tutorial?

Tags: ipv6

How do I get started on IPv6?

There are many urban myths about IPv6 (today, I heard that enterprises don't like IPv6 because they can't control their BLOCKS like they do today with IPv4). Is there a list which dispells those?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent resource for IPv6 information is the IRC channel called "`#ipv6`" on irc.freenode.net.  The folks here are very helpful, and I've seen myths being dispelled on this channel quite a few times over the past few years.

As far as netblock management is concerned, ARIN.net generally provides the same style of management for IPv6 as it always has for IPv4, with the main difference being that IPv6 netblocks tend to be much larger.

I suspect that what spooks some people is how IPv6 addresses are normally represented with hexadecimal nybbles and colons instead of decimal digits and periods (as is normally the case with IPv4).  Add to that the optional double-colon ("::") notation that makes it possible to compress a portion of your IPv6 address, and some people can get really confused when they're not familiar with this aspect of the addressing scheme.

Excellent information about IPv6 can be found in RFC 3513:

RFC 3513 - Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) Addressing Architecture
  http://rfc3513.openrfc.org/

That document includes examples of using the notation (including "compression" by using the double-colon {"::"}).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.secondinternet.org has a free IPv6 book.

Comment: Unfortunately, this website no longer seems to host anything related to ipv6.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out [HurricaneElectric](http://he.net) and [HE Tunnel Broker](http://tunnelbroker.net) they are a large IPv6 tunnel broker. They offer free IPv6 tunnels and have a very good training section.